# How do I make css only affect one button, rather than all of them?

Tags: css, button

I have a page that has multiple buttons.  I want to change one of them using css, but can't seem to figure out how to do that in CSS, without changing all of them.

```
<p>
     <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#acne" class="collapsed">Acne</button>
</p>
<div id="acne" class="collapse">
    <ul>
        <li>Blackheads</li>
        <li>Whiteheads</li>
        <li>Pimples</li>
        <li>Nodules or cysts</li>
        <li>Redness or flushing</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>
     <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#backpain">Back Pain</button>
</p>
<div id="backpain" class="collapse">
    <ul>
        <li>Pain in the lower back</li>
        <li>Pain, numbness, or tingling on one side of the buttocks or leg</li>
        <li>Weakness of the muscles in one leg</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like the button for Acne to be a different color and size.  ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: consider attribute selector : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Can you add a class attribute to the one you want to style? Can you edit the HTML?

Comment: add `id="uniquebutton"` to the div containing "Acne", and then add `#uniquebutton{height: (bigger than other button; width: (bigger than other button); background: (different color than other button}` to your CSS. Obviously, change the values of (bigger than other button) to the values of your choice. Same for color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the button an [ID attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) or a [class attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

IDs are unique, while classes can consist of one or more elements.